# Static List in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

I would like to create a static list on Kibana Dashboard.
For example, a pane displaying clickable region names. So when I click on a region, rest of the visualizations change dynamically.

I am looking for something like 'Metric' visualization but for text data and clickable.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar, not fully static, but you can create a Data Table visualization (in Kibana4).

On that table, filter by the logs that interest you (with the metric types for example) and that will create a row for each metric type. Add that table visualization to the dashboard where you need the 'clickable filter'.

Then, clicking a row in that table will filter the entire dashboard based on that specific metric-type.